# Youtube scraping with selenium :not getting all comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape youtube comments using selenium with python. Below is the code which scrapes just the one comment and throws error

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNltVQqJhRE"
driver.get(url)

wait(driver, 5500)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight + 500);")
driver.implicitly_wait(5000)

#content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]')
comm=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="style-scope ytd-item-section-renderer"]')
comm1=comm.find_elements_by_xpath('//yt-formatted-string[@id="content-text"]')
#print(comm.text)
for i in range(50):
    print(comm1[i].text,end=' ')
```

This is the output I am getting. How do I get all the comments on that page??? Can anyone help me with this.

```
 Being a sucessful phyton freelancer really mean to me because if I able to make $2000 in month I can really help my family financial, improve my skill, and have a lot of time to refreshing. So thanks Qazi, you really help me :D 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\programs\Web scrap\YT_Comm.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(comm1[i].text,end=' ')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 5):

An `IndexError` means you’re attempting to access a position in a list that doesn’t exist. You’re iterating over your list of elements (`comm1`) exactly 50 times, but there are fewer than 50 elements in the list, so eventually you attempt to access an index that doesn’t exist.

Superficially, you can solve your problem by changing your iteration to loop over *exactly* as many elements as exist in your list—no more and no less:

```py
for element in comm1:
    print(element.text, end=‘ ‘)
```

But that leaves you with the problem of *why* your list has fewer than 50 elements. The video you’re scraping has over 90 comments. Why doesn’t your list have all of them?

If you take a look at the page in your browser, you'll see that the comments load progressively using the [infinite scroll](https://xkcd.com/1309/) technique: when the user scrolls to the bottom of the document, another "page" of comments are fetched and rendered, increasing the length of the document. To load more comments, you will need to trigger this behavior.

But depending on the number of comments, **one fetch may not be enough.** In order to trigger the fetch and rendering of all of the content, then, you will need to:

1. attempt to **trigger a fetch of additional content**, then
2. **determine whether additional content was fetched**, and, if so,
3. **repeat** (because there might be *even more*).

## Triggering a fetch

We already know that additional content is fetched by scrolling to the bottom of the content container (the element with `id` `#contents`), so let's do that:

```py
driver.execute_script(
    "window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector('#contents').scrollHeight);")
```

(Note: Because the content resides in an `absolute`-positioned element, `document.body.scrollHeight` will always be `0` and will not trigger a scroll.)

### Waiting for the content container

But as with any browser automation, we're in a race with the application: What if the content container hasn't rendered yet? Our scroll would fail.

Selenium provides [`WebDriverWait()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait) to help you wait for the application to be in a particular state. It also provides, via its [`expected_conditions`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) module, a set of common states to wait for, such as the presence of an element. We can use both of these to wait for the content container to be present:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 10

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS)
wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#contents")))
```

## Determining whether additional content was fetched

At a high level, we can determine whether additional content was fetched by:

1. **counting the content *before*** we trigger the fetch,
2. **counting the content *after*** we trigger the fetch, then
3. **comparing** the two.

### Counting the content

Within our container (with `id` `"#contents"`), each piece of content has `id` `#content`. To count the content, we can simply fetch each of those elements and use Python's built-in `len()`:

```py
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#contents #content")
```

#### Handling a slow render

But again, we're in a race with the application: What happens if either the fetch or the render of additional content is slow? We won't immediately see it.

We need to give the web application time to do its thing. To do this, we can use `WebDriverWait()` with a custom condition:

```py
def get_count():
    return len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#contents #content"))

count = get_count()
# ...
wait.until(
    lambda _: get_count() > count)
```

#### Handling no additional content

But what if there *isn't* any additional content? Our wait for the count to increase will timeout.

**As long as our timeout is high enough** to allow sufficient time for the additional content to appear, **we can assume that there is no additional content** and ignore the timeout:

```py
try:
    wait.until(
        lambda _: get_count() > count)
except TimeoutException:
    # No additional content appeared. Abort our loop.
    break
```

## Putting it all together

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 10

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS)

driver.get(URL)

wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#contents")))

def get_count():
    return len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#contents #content"))

while True:
    count = get_count()
    driver.execute_script(
        "window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector('#contents').scrollHeight);")
    try:
        wait.until(
            lambda _: get_count() > initial_count)
    except TimeoutException:
        # No additional content appeared. Abort our loop.
        break

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#contents #content")
```

## Bonus: Simplifying with capybara-py

With [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py), this becomes a bit simpler:

```
import capybara
from capybara.dsl import page
from capybara.exceptions import ExpectationNotMet

@capybara.register_driver("selenium_chrome")
def init_selenium_chrome_driver(app):
    from capybara.selenium.driver import Driver
    return Driver(app, browser="chrome")

capybara.current_driver = "selenium_chrome"
capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10

page.visit(URL)

contents = page.find("#contents")

elements = []
while True:
    try:
        elements = contents.find_all("#content", minimum=len(elements) + 1)
    except ExpectationNotMet:
        # No additional content appeared. Abort our loop.
        break

    page.execute_script(
        "window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", contents)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.But i need youtube comments for my project.So i just learned basics of selenium to scrap with python.Can you provide a code with a youtube link that can give the comment of that video

Comment: @Anesh The purpose of this site is to get answers to specific technical problems—not to crowdsource whole programs. I updated the beginning of my answer to provide a little more context on the problem with your code and why my answer addresses it. With it, you should be able to update your script to make it work. If there is anything confusing about my answer, please leave a comment so that I can refine it; if you need help with a new problem, please post a new question.

Comment: Iam sryy.You gave gud explanation.Just one question.You used css selector.Can I use other selectors too??

Comment: @Anesh Absolutely. Selenium supports a variety of ways of searching for elements. Capybara supports an even greater set of options. (It’s worth noting, however, that the queries in your question only use tag names, ids, and class names, which don’t require something as complicated or powerful as XPath.)

Comment: Thank you.I used beatiful soup for scraping but it could not scrap youtube comments so i tried selenium.Now I will try capybara also.